# Parsing XML into JSON with XSL

Tags: xslt

I am triyng to convert the xml file into json using xsl but i am unable to get the output can body help me out.

I tried many ways to do but the output is not coming .

My XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="data">
    <!-- Import common templates -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <!-- Root template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
            {
            "manifest":
            <xsl:for-each select="manifests">
                <xsl:for-each select="manifest">
                {
                    "consignments":
                    {
                       "consignment":
                             <xsl:for-each select="consignments">
                                 <xsl:for-each select="consignment">
                            {
                                 "owner":
                                     {
                                         "participant":
                                             <xsl:for-each select="owner">
                                                 <xsl:for-each select="participant">
                                                  {
                                                     "type":"<xsl:value-of select="type" />",
                                                     "licenseType":"<xsl:value-of select="licenseType" />",
                                                     "businessNumber":"<xsl:value-of select="businessNumber" />",
                                                     "businessName":"<xsl:value-of select="businessName" />",
                                                     "tradingName":"<xsl:value-of select="tradingName" />"
                                                  }
                                                 </xsl:for-each>
                                             </xsl:for-each>
                                     },
                                     {
                                        "consignmentNumber":"<xsl:value-of select="consignmentNumber" />"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "freightStateName":"<xsl:value-of select="freightStateName" />"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "shipper":
                                             {
                                                 "participant":
                                                         <xsl:for-each select="shipper">
                                                             <xsl:for-each select="participant">
                                                                 {
                                                                     "type":"<xsl:value-of select="type" />", 
                                                                     "licenseType":"<xsl:value-of select="licenseType" />",
                                                                     "businessName":"<xsl:value-of select="businessName" />",
                                                                     "tradingName":"<xsl:value-of select="tradingName" />"
                                                                 }
                                                             </xsl:for-each>
                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                              }
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "id":"<xsl:value-of select="id" />"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "despatchDate":"<xsl:value-of select="despatchDate" />"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "actualDespatchDate":"<xsl:value-of select="actualDespatchDate" />"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "expectedDeliveryDate":"<xsl:value-of select="expectedDeliveryDate" />"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "creationDate":"<xsl:value-of select="creationDate" />"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "pickUpAddress":
                                        {     
                                             "address":  
                                            {    <xsl:for-each select="pickUpAddress">
                                                             <xsl:for-each select="address">

                                                 "owner":
                                                 {
                                                     "participant":
                                                         <xsl:for-each select="owner">
                                                             <xsl:for-each select="participant">
                                                             {
                                                                 "businessName":"<xsl:value-of select="businessName" />"
                                                             }
                                                             </xsl:for-each>
                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "line1":"<xsl:value-of select="line1"/>"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "line2":"<xsl:value-of select="line2"/>"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "town":"<xsl:value-of select="town" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "state":"<xsl:value-of select="state" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "postcode":"<xsl:value-of select="postcode" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "unloadSequence":"<xsl:value-of select="unloadSequence" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "addressReferenceId":"<xsl:value-of select="addressReferenceId" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "preferredJourneyId":"<xsl:value-of select="preferredJourneyId" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "specialInstructions":"<xsl:value-of select="specialInstructions" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "deliveryCloseTime":"<xsl:value-of select="deliveryCloseTime" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "deliveryOpenTime":"<xsl:value-of select="deliveryOpenTime" />"
                                                 }
                                                 </xsl:for-each>
                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                            }

                                        }

                                    },
                                    {
                                      "pickupZoneExternalID":"<xsl:value-of select="pickupZoneExternalID" />"
                                    },
                                    {
                                         "deliveryAddress":
                                        {     
                                             "address":  
                                            {    <xsl:for-each select="deliveryAddress">
                                                             <xsl:for-each select="address">

                                                 "owner":
                                                 {
                                                     "participant":
                                                         <xsl:for-each select="owner">
                                                             <xsl:for-each select="participant">
                                                             {
                                                                 "businessName":"<xsl:value-of select="businessName" />"
                                                             }
                                                             </xsl:for-each>
                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "line1":"<xsl:value-of select="line1"/>"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "line2":"<xsl:value-of select="line2"/>"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "line3":"<xsl:value-of select="line3"/>"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "line4":"<xsl:value-of select="line4"/>"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "town":"<xsl:value-of select="town" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "state":"<xsl:value-of select="state" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "postcode":"<xsl:value-of select="postcode" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "contactName":"<xsl:value-of select="contactName" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "contactPhone":"<xsl:value-of select="contactPhone" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "customerGroup":"<xsl:value-of select="customerGroup" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "addressReferenceId":"<xsl:value-of select="addressReferenceId" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "specialInstructions":"<xsl:value-of select="specialInstructions" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "deliveryCloseTime":"<xsl:value-of select="deliveryCloseTime" />"
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                     "deliveryOpenTime":"<xsl:value-of select="deliveryOpenTime" />"
                                                 }
                                                 </xsl:for-each>
                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                            }     
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "deliveryZoneExternalID":<xsl:value-of select="deliveryZoneExternalID" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "chargeAccount":<xsl:value-of select="chargeAccount" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "returnConsignment":<xsl:value-of select="returnConsignment" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "service":
                                       {
                                          "carrier";
                                          {
                                             "participant":
                                                 <xsl:for-each select="service">
                                                     <xsl:for-each select="carrier">
                                                         <xsl:for-each select="participant">
                                                         {
                                                             "businessName":"<xsl:value-of select="businessName" />" 
                                                         }
                                                 </xsl:for-each>
                                                     </xsl:for-each>
                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                          }
                                       }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "journey":
                                             <xsl:for-each select="journey">
                                                 {
                                                     "owner": 
                                                     {
                                                         "participant":
                                                             <xsl:for-each select="owner">
                                                                 <xsl:for-each select="participant">
                                                                 {
                                                                     "businessName":"<xsl:value-of select="businessName" />" 
                                                                 }
                                                                 </xsl:for-each>
                                                             </xsl:for-each>      
                                                     },
                                                     {
                                                       "legService":
                                                       <xsl:for-each select="legService">
                                                       {
                                                         "owner": 
                                                             {
                                                                 "participant":
                                                                     <xsl:for-each select="owner">
                                                                         <xsl:for-each select="participant">
                                                                     {
                                                                         "businessName":"<xsl:value-of select="businessName" />" 
                                                                     }
                                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                                                     </xsl:for-each>      
                                                             },
                                                             {
                                                                "leg":
                                                                    {
                                                                         "owner": 
                                                                             {
                                                                                 "participant":
                                                                                 <xsl:for-each select="leg">
                                                                                     <xsl:for-each select="owner">
                                                                                         <xsl:for-each select="participant">
                                                                                                 {
                                                                                                      "businessName":"<xsl:value-of select="businessName" />" 
                                                                                                 }
                                                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                                                                     </xsl:for-each>
                                                                                 </xsl:for-each>     
                                                                              }
                                                                    }
                                                             },
                                                             {
                                                                "service":
                                                                     {
                                                                         "carrier";
                                                                             {
                                                                                 "participant":
                                                                                     <xsl:for-each select="service">
                                                                                         <xsl:for-each select="carrier">
                                                                                             <xsl:for-each select="participant">
                                                                                                 {
                                                                                                     "businessName":"<xsl:value-of select="businessName" />" 
                                                                                                 }
                                                                                             </xsl:for-each>
                                                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                                                                      </xsl:for-each>
                                                                              }
                                                                     } 
                                                             }

                                                       }
                                                       </xsl:for-each>
                                                     }
                                                 }
                                             </xsl:for-each>
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "specialInstructions":<xsl:value-of select="specialInstructions" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "rate":<xsl:value-of select="rate" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "rateIncSurcharge":<xsl:value-of select="rateIncSurcharge" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "rateWithoutMargin":<xsl:value-of select="rateWithoutMargin" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "rateWithoutMarginIncSurcharge":<xsl:value-of select="rateWithoutMarginIncSurcharge" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "weight":<xsl:value-of select="weight" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "volume":<xsl:value-of select="volume" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "extensions":<xsl:value-of select="extensions" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                     "lineItems":
                                         {
                                             "lineItem":
                                                 <xsl:for-each select="lineItems">
                                                     <xsl:for-each select="lineItem">
                                                     {
                                                         "id":<xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                                                     },
                                                     {
                                                         "volume":<xsl:value-of select="volume"/>
                                                     },
                                                     {
                                                         "weight":<xsl:value-of select="weight"/> 
                                                     },
                                                     {
                                                       "extensions":
                                                         {
                                                             "unconsolidatedLineItemRateExtension":
                                                                     <xsl:for-each select="extensions">
                                                                         <xsl:for-each select="unconsolidatedLineItemRateExtension">
                                                                             {

                                                                               "consolidatedBuyRate":<xsl:value-of select="consolidatedBuyRate" />,
                                                                               "consolidatedSellRate":<xsl:value-of select="consolidatedSellRate" />,
                                                                               "unConsolidatedBuyRate":<xsl:value-of select="unConsolidatedBuyRate" />,
                                                                               "unConsolidatedSellRate":<xsl:value-of select="unConsolidatedSellRate" />
                                                                             }
                                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                                                     </xsl:for-each>
                                                         }
                                                     },
                                                     {
                                                       "container":
                                                             {
                                                                 "references":
                                                                     <xsl:for-each select="container">
                                                                         <xsl:for-each select="references">
                                                                             {
                                                                                 "reference":<xsl:value-of select="reference" />
                                                                             }
                                                                         </xsl:for-each>
                                                                     </xsl:for-each>
                                                             }
                                                     },
                                                     {
                                                       "totalLabels":<xsl:value-of select="totalLabels"/>
                                                     }
                                                     </xsl:for-each>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                         }
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "silentMode":<xsl:value-of select="silentMode" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "forceDespatchToCarrier":<xsl:value-of select="forceDespatchToCarrier" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "autoDespatch":<xsl:value-of select="autoDespatch" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "autoDeliver":<xsl:value-of select="autoDeliver" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "actualLongDespatchTime":<xsl:value-of select="actualLongDespatchTime" />
                                    },
                                    {
                                      "useSlaveDeliveryAddress":<xsl:value-of select="useSlaveDeliveryAddress" />
                                    }
                                  </xsl:for-each>
                              </xsl:for-each> 
                            }
                    }                   
                }
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
            }

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifests xmlns="http://www.moveit.com.au/schema/data.xsd">
  <manifest ref="false">
    <manifestNumber>20161214141153978</manifestNumber>
    <despatchDate>2016-10-04T23:30:00</despatchDate>
    <actualDespatchDate>2016-12-14T14:11:54</actualDespatchDate>
    <shipper>
      <participant ref="true">
        <type>shipper</type>
        <licenseType>ACCESS</licenseType>
        <businessName>PMP LIMITED</businessName>
        <tradingName>PMP LIMITED</tradingName>
      </participant>
    </shipper>
    <pickUpAddress>
      <address externalId="BL" category="" ref="true">
        <owner>
          <participant ref="true">
            <businessName>PMP LIMITED</businessName>
          </participant>
        </owner>
        <country id="AU" name="Australia" countryCode="AU" />
        <line1>PMP Print - Bibra Lake</line1>
        <line2>51 Miguel Road</line2>
        <town>BIBRA LAKE</town>
        <state>WA</state>
        <postcode>6163</postcode>
        <unloadSequence>0</unloadSequence>
        <addressReferenceId>BL</addressReferenceId>
        <preferredJourneyId />
        <specialInstructions />
        <deliveryCloseTime />
        <deliveryOpenTime />
      </address>
    </pickUpAddress>
    <deliveryAddress>
      <address copyOf="Big W Kingsway Cnr Wanneroo Road &amp;" category="" ref="true">
        <owner>
          <participant ref="true">
            <businessName>PMP LIMITED</businessName>
          </participant>
        </owner>
        <country id="AU" name="Australia" countryCode="AU" />
        <line1>Big W Kingsway</line1>
        <line2>Cnr Wanneroo Road &amp;</line2>
        <line3>Hepburn Avenue</line3>
        <line4 />
        <town>LANDSDALE</town>
        <state>WA</state>
        <postcode>6065</postcode>
        <contactName />
        <contactPhone />
        <customerGroup />
        <addressReferenceId>Big W Kingsway Cnr Wanneroo Road &amp;</addressReferenceId>
        <specialInstructions />
        <deliveryCloseTime />
        <deliveryOpenTime />
      </address>
    </deliveryAddress>
    <rate>0</rate>
    <totalLineItemContainers>2</totalLineItemContainers>
    <weight>10</weight>
    <volume>0</volume>
    <extensions />
    <consignments>
      <consignment ref="true">
        <owner>
          <participant ref="true">
            <type>carrier</type>
            <licenseType>ACCESS</licenseType>
            <businessNumber>9998888999</businessNumber>
            <businessName>PMP CLIENT PICKUP</businessName>
            <tradingName>PMP CLIENT PICKUP</tradingName>
          </participant>
        </owner>
        <consignmentNumber>BLCP000653</consignmentNumber>
        <freightStateName>In Transit</freightStateName>
        <shipper>
          <participant ref="true">
            <type>shipper</type>
            <licenseType>ACCESS</licenseType>
            <businessName>PMP LIMITED</businessName>
            <tradingName>PMP LIMITED</tradingName>
          </participant>
        </shipper>
        <id>3377699720845488</id>
        <despatchDate>2016-10-04</despatchDate>
        <actualDespatchDate>2016-12-14T14:11:54</actualDespatchDate>
        <expectedDeliveryDate>2016-10-05</expectedDeliveryDate>
        <creationDate>2016-10-05</creationDate>
        <pickUpAddress>
          <address copyOf="BL" category="" ref="true">
            <owner>
              <participant ref="true">
                <businessName>PMP LIMITED</businessName>
              </participant>
            </owner>
            <country id="AU" name="Australia" countryCode="AU" />
            <line1>PMP Print - Bibra Lake</line1>
            <line2>51 Miguel Road</line2>
            <town>BIBRA LAKE</town>
            <state>WA</state>
            <postcode>6163</postcode>
            <unloadSequence>0</unloadSequence>
            <addressReferenceId>BL</addressReferenceId>
            <preferredJourneyId />
            <specialInstructions />
            <deliveryCloseTime />
            <deliveryOpenTime />
          </address>
        </pickUpAddress>
        <pickupZoneExternalID>/PMP_CLIENT_PICKUP_ZONES/AUS</pickupZoneExternalID>
        <deliveryAddress>
          <address copyOf="Big W Kingsway Cnr Wanneroo Road &amp;" category="" ref="true">
            <owner>
              <participant ref="true">
                <businessName>PMP LIMITED</businessName>
              </participant>
            </owner>
            <country id="AU" name="Australia" countryCode="AU" />
            <line1>Big W Kingsway</line1>
            <line2>Cnr Wanneroo Road &amp;</line2>
            <line3>Hepburn Avenue</line3>
            <line4 />
            <town>LANDSDALE</town>
            <state>WA</state>
            <postcode>6065</postcode>
            <contactName />
            <contactPhone />
            <customerGroup />
            <addressReferenceId>Big W Kingsway Cnr Wanneroo Road &amp;</addressReferenceId>
            <specialInstructions />
            <deliveryCloseTime />
            <deliveryOpenTime />
          </address>
        </deliveryAddress>
        <deliveryZoneExternalID>/PMP_CLIENT_PICKUP_ZONES/AUS</deliveryZoneExternalID>
        <chargeAccount chargeParty="shipper" />
        <returnConsignment>false</returnConsignment>
        <service name="ROAD EXPRESS" workingDaysOnly="false" ref="true">
          <carrier>
            <participant ref="true">
              <businessName>PMP CLIENT PICKUP</businessName>
            </participant>
          </carrier>
        </service>
        <journey name="PMP CLIENT PICKUP ROAD EXPRESS" ref="true">
          <owner>
            <participant ref="true">
              <businessName>PMP CLIENT PICKUP</businessName>
            </participant>
          </owner>
          <legService ref="true">
            <owner>
              <participant ref="true">
                <businessName>PMP CLIENT PICKUP</businessName>
              </participant>
            </owner>
            <leg name="ROAD EXPRESS" ref="true">
              <owner>
                <participant ref="true">
                  <businessName>PMP CLIENT PICKUP</businessName>
                </participant>
              </owner>
            </leg>
            <service name="ROAD EXPRESS" workingDaysOnly="false" ref="true">
              <carrier>
                <participant ref="true">
                  <businessName>PMP CLIENT PICKUP</businessName>
                </participant>
              </carrier>
            </service>
          </legService>
        </journey>
        <specialInstructions />
        <rate>0</rate>
        <rateIncSurcharge>0</rateIncSurcharge>
        <rateWithoutMargin>0</rateWithoutMargin>
        <rateWithoutMarginIncSurcharge>0</rateWithoutMarginIncSurcharge>
        <weight>10</weight>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <extensions />
        <lineItems>
          <lineItem description="300" costCode="WA Store">
            <id>16888498607755132</id>
            <volume>0</volume>
            <weight>10</weight>
            <extensions>
              <unconsolidatedLineItemRateExtension>
                <consolidatedBuyRate>0.00</consolidatedBuyRate>
                <consolidatedSellRate>0.00</consolidatedSellRate>
                <unConsolidatedBuyRate>0.00</unConsolidatedBuyRate>
                <unConsolidatedSellRate>0.00</unConsolidatedSellRate>
              </unconsolidatedLineItemRateExtension>
            </extensions>
            <container unit="Carton" amount="2" weight="5" length="0" width="0" height="0" volume="0" uomRank="1" labelCopies="1">
              <references stringValue="MKBIGW1623 - Big W PEFC 24pp os 13.10">
                <reference>MKBIGW1623 - Big W PEFC 24pp os 13.10</reference>
              </references>
            </container>
            <totalLabels>0</totalLabels>
          </lineItem>
        </lineItems>
        <silentMode>false</silentMode>
        <forceDespatchToCarrier />
        <autoDespatch>false</autoDespatch>
        <autoDeliver>false</autoDeliver>
        <actualLongDespatchTime>1481686914328</actualLongDespatchTime>
        <useSlaveDeliveryAddress>false</useSlaveDeliveryAddress>
      </consignment>
    </consignments>
    <silentMode>false</silentMode>
    <autoDespatch>false</autoDespatch>
    <autoDeliver>false</autoDeliver>
  </manifest>
</manifests>
```

These are the file on which i have worked.

Comment: I tried to do some way you can find below:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"exclude-result-prefixes="data"><!-- Import common templates --<xsl:outputmethod="xml" indent="yes" /><!-- Root template --><xsl:template match="/">{"manifest":<xsl:for-each select="manifests"><xsl:for-each select="manifest">{"consignments":{"consignment":<xsl:for-each select="consignments"><xsl:for-each select="consignment">{"consignmentNumber":"<xsl:value-of select="consignmentNumber" />"} </xsl:for-each></xsl:for-each>}}</xsl:for-each></xsl:for-each>}</xsl:template>

Comment: Please edit your question to include the XSLT sample. To do this simply click the "edit" link under the question, paste in the code, select it all to highlight it, and click the `{}` button to format it as code to make it readable. It would also help if you showed your input XML and your expected output. Thank you!

Comment: What output are you expecting, what output are you seeing and if your sample code is in the comment, edit your question and add it there instead.

Comment: I am trying to get the data of consignment

Comment: can you help me ....

Comment: You have written a lot of code already but start simple and test and you will find that your first selection `<xsl:for-each select="manifests">` already does not select anything as your input XML has a default namespace declaration `manifests xmlns="http://www.moveit.com.au/schema/data.xsd"` in place. How to handle that has been shown in lots of answers here already or in the XSLT FAQ like http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N5536.html#d7042e187 so follow that advice there or switch to an XSLT 2.0 processor and add `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.moveit.com.au/schema/data.xsd"` to your XSL

Comment: See http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVz on how your code starts working with an XSLT 2.0 processor and the suggestion made in my earlier comment.

Comment: In addition to handling the default namespace, you should also change your output method to `text`.

Comment: When i tried to switch my xsl to 2.0 and added  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.moveit.com.au/schema/dat‌​a.xsd" then it is giving exception that  "xpath-default-namespace" attribute is not allowed on the xsl:stylesheet element.

Comment: Well, to use XSLT 2.0 you need to download, install and use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or Altova, Saxon 9 HE is open source and available in a .NET and a Java version from Sourceforge. Or you can use it online as shown in the link http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVz posted. If you want to use an XSLT 1.0 processor then use the advice in the FAQ to change your XSLT to use a prefix to qualify the element names.

Comment: not able to find FAQ where i can get help so can you send me some links

Comment: i have written the parser in java in which the xml will be coming and it will read the xsl and convert it into that format just i need the correct xsl format for json .So please send me the links